# how to download a file into a specified directory in php?

Tags: php, download

How i can download a csv file into a specified directory.?
Now I used this code,

```
header("Location:uploads/".$dire);
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$nn);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Here, `$dire` is the sub directory of upload folder and `$nn` is the csv file name.
I want to download this `$nn` file and saved in a specified directory `$dire`.
But the it shows an error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean you want to be in control of the download location by the client, then I'm afraid its not possible with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control that behviour of client (webbrowser).